# How to avoid pyMysql callprocedure error?

Tags: mysql-python

I try to write all sql sytax/queries on python as on the work bench, but I can't run cursor.callproc().
my code : [sqq.py](https://file.io/RTPpFJgXnT4f)

result :

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'get()' at line 1